# Find the point of intersection

Tags: vectors

Show that the line jointing the points (2,2,-1) and (3,4,2) intersects the line joining the points (7,0,6) and (2,5,1). Also find the point of intersection?

Comment: Create two sets of parametric equations of the lines by finding a vector parallel to them. Then, you may set those equal to each other to find the intersection point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A point on the line joining $(2,2,-1)$ and $(3,4,2)$ has the coordinates $(2t+3(1-t),2t+4(1-t),-t+2(1-t))$ in general.  If it is also on the line joining $(7,0,6)$ and $(2,5,1)$, then its coordinates can also be written as $(7s+2(1-s),5(1-s),6s+(1-s))$.

Solving $\begin{cases} 2t+3(1-t)=7s+2(1-s) \\ 2t+4(1-t)=5(1-s) \\ -t+2(1-t)=6s+(1-s)\end{cases}$, we can find the point.

Note: If the system has no solution, it means that the two lines do not intersect.